# How to obtain file name from URI object in C++/WinRT

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt, cppwinrt

I am working on a C++WinRT UWP app. I have URI object which contains the file path for downloading file over the internet. I want to extract only the file name with extension from this URI object. I want to create a local file with this name. Is there a library method to do this? Appreciate the help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question is rooted in a fundamental misunderstanding. File names are meaningful only in context of a file system. The HTTP protocol (which you are presumably using) does not model a file system.

[URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)s

> identify a logical or physical resource used by web technologies. URIs may be used to identify **anything**, including real-world objects, such as people and places, concepts, or information resources such as web pages and books.

Consequently, the [Uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.uri) type does not limit itself to identifying files, and as such does not provide properties or methods to extract a file name (which may or may not exist after all).

If you are lucky the server you are communicating with provides a `filename` parameter in the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) response header which you can use as a file name for local storage.

If not you will have to invent a file name of your choosing.